# Disable a UI button at launch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, viewdidload

I am stuck trying to disable a UIButton at launch. I want the button to be disabled at launch and to be able to enable it using other buttons within the app.

I can disable it in the .xib from the attributes inspector, but then the following code does not re-enable it.

```
bankButton.enabled = Yes;
bankButton.alpha = 1.0f;
```

Or I can try to disable it in the viewDidLoad method with:

```
bankButton.enabled = No;
bankButton.alpha = .00f;
```

But that does not work, because I believe the enable checkbox on the .xib overrides that? Im guessing.

What can I do to have it disabled at launch, and enabled upon button press.

Comment: If you *believe* it overrides it, why not *test* it first?

Comment: I did test it and it does not work that way.. im assuming because it overrides. thanks for the excellent comment

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
editButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

or

```
button.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Tried both in viewDidLoad method. Neither gave me the ability to disable the button off the bat. Both do work to disable once the app is already running tho - just not what I need it for!

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the IBOutlet to the button in IB?
Also, change Yes to YES. And No to NO.

The enable checkbox in IB does not override what you do in code. It's the other way around.

Comment: Yup, everything is linked and working properly. I can enable and disable it once the app is running but only if it starts as enabled. I want to start with that button disabled.

Comment: use userInteractionEnabled.

Comment: that does work if I put it in a button to use after the app is running. Does not seem to work to disable the button off the bat, on app launch.

Comment: also, thanks much for the info on the IB settings being second priority to the code.. I was hoping that would be the case.

Comment: Move it to viewWillAppear. Your IBOutlets probably are not yet initialized where you are calling it.

Comment: This is the weirdest thing. After implementing this, the bank button is still available after launching the app. If I bring up a new view, the go back to the first view, then bankButton is disabled. Why wont this disable on launch!?

Comment: If you are disabling it on viewWillAppear (or viewDidLoad), then you are re-enabling it somewhere else. Find anywhere that you are enabling the button and log when that code gets fired, and I'll bet it gets fired after viewWillAppear gets fired on your first launch.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting disable in viewWillAppear method. It will disable the button during launch and you can re-enable in using another buttons action.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    bankButton.enabled = FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: This is the weirdest thing. After implementing this, the bank button is still available after launching the app. If I bring up a new view, the go back to the first view, then bankButton is disabled. Why wont this disable on launch!?

Answer (score 0):

I did not have my @property lines linked to the objects! Make sure to do so.